# How do I drop the TIME portion from DATEADD?

Tags: sql-server, update, datetime, date-format, date

I am trying to create some test data where each Employee has a random birthdate. I accomplished the randomizing part but it did not return result in the format that I want.. NOTE: the DateOfBirth column uses the VARCHAR data type.

```
/****** Generate Random Date For Each Row (Between 1900 - 2015) ******/
UPDATE CCCINC.dbo.Employees
SET DateOfBirth = DATEADD(DAY, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 41975), '1900-01-01');
```

Result:

```
Feb 28 1930 12:00AM
```

How do I remove the TIME portion from the result? Also, if I wanted to change the DATE format to YYYYMMDD how would I accomplish that?

Comment: WHY does the `DateOfBirth` column use `VARCHAR` and not `DATE`? Do you also store numbers as strings and try to stuff last names into date columns?

Comment: @AaronBertrand That was just how the programmer designed it. Agree that it is not optimal but that's what I'm working with.

Comment: So the developer chose the wrong data type and you don't have the ability to fix it using `ALTER TABLE`?

Comment: @ypercube that still produces a time component (it's just midnight).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, assuming that someone is holding a gun to your head, forcing you to not change the data type to something more sensible and logical:

```
UPDATE CCCINC.dbo.Employees
SET DateOfBirth = CONVERT(CHAR(8), DATEADD(DAY, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) 
  % 41975), '1900-01-01'), 112);
```

Strong, strongly, strongly suggest you change the data type of that column to use the right data type (`DATE`). Then you can just use your original query and not worry about the "format" at all. Format is what you worry about when you *present* the data, not when you *store* it.

- [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)
- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: Comes with the territory of QA'ing the new programmer's application. I already submitted a request to change the data type but until that fix is pushed to deployment I had to find a work around. Thank you for the help.